# Staggered Gridview orientation change

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I am using etsy Staggered Grid View its works fine in both orientations when the number of columns is not specified but views are not repositioned properly during orientation change in case if the number of columns is fixed

Comment: @andreimarinescu I explicitly specified not to handle orientation change for that activity in manifest file